# How to remove zero's in python datetime

Tags: python

I'm trying to use a loop to remove some dates from a dataframe, but `datetime(some_date)+datetime.timedelta(days=1)` results in something like `datetime.datetime(2019,8,6,0,0)`, which is causing my code to crash. Is there any way to remove these zeros?

Edit:
Here's the error

```
KeyError: '[datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 6, 0, 0)] not found in axis'
```

Here is the code the error is referring to

```
for i in range(51):
   data.drop([datetime(2019,8,5)+timedelta(days=1)],inplace=True)
```

And sorry if my question isn't very clear this is my first time.

Comment: Please show us a complete example, because your description doesn't make sense.  A `datetime` plus a `timedelta` is always going to result in a valid `datetime`.  And a `datetime` always has a time element.  If you only specify a date, the time will be 00:00:00.

Comment: The reason for the "crash" is most likely your code and not the datetime. Post the code and the full error traceback!

Answer (score 1):

I may be misinterpreting your question, but this is what I think you're asking...

In datetime.datetime(), the five numbers entered are for (year,month,day,hour,minute). The zeroes you are referring to are occupying the hour and minute spots, so I think you are asking for this to be a date-only equation. Yes?
If so, the datetime module has a built-in method for that: datetime.date()

```
    import datetime

    some_date=datetime.date(2019,8,6)
    y=some_date+datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    print(y)
```

The results will be "2019-08-07"...Does that answer your question?